# Immortality research, skin becomes calcified -- title?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie maybe in the 1960s. I think it was nazi mad scientist on an island -- are there enough isolated islands for all the nazi mad scientists? -- trying to extend life.

The side effect involves the skin stiffening due to mineralization. I recall a character to whom this happened was named Eric; the visitors to the nazi island thought he had Down syndrome iirc but they used the disfavored term "Mongolism" (the movie was also made in the 1960s I think).

**Edit: Not nazis at all but from 1700s (i am sure politically conservative nonetheless).**

Comment: Just wanna give a honorable mention to [Catwoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catwoman_(film)). Of course it doesn't fit, but people searching for this title might end up here.

Comment: Catwoman?? Why? Not understanding connection.

Comment: Because the evil company in the movie is working on an anti aging creme, which of course goes wrong and pretty much turns the main evil lady's skin into stone. So it doesn't fit the question's body, but fits the title quite well.

Comment: ahh, did not know plot of catwoman very well and these guys are working on immortality not just skin appearance.

Comment: Anti aging and immortality can get switched up easily if memories are incomplete, that's why ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [The Man Who Turned to Stone](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050675/?ref_=tt_urv) (1957).

> Jory and his followers stay immortal by siphoning off the life forces of others. If they don't get renewed, they petrify.
>
> [image]

Note the presence of Friedrich von Ledebur as 'Eric'

Comment: i think so! and there was an "Eric" in it.

Comment: Why will I too be petrified with suspence if the trailer already told me the secret of what's happening to those women? :-(

Comment: @einpoklum - You'll have to watch it to find out.